# Question on strict order of a disjoint union

Tags: proof-writing, order-theory, proof-explanation

We consider two strict ordered set $(A,<_A)$ and $(B,<_B)$ and we define the set $(X,<_X)$ with $X=A\sqcup B$ and $u<_X v\Leftrightarrow (u,v\in A , u<_A v$) or ($u,v\in B, u<_B v$) or ($u\in A$ and $v\in B$).

So is $(X,<_X)$ a strict ordered set ?

The answer is trivial for the two first cases because $<_A$ and $<_B$ define strict order. But the last case I don't see why because we can't compare $u,v$. Same problem if the two sets are totally or well-ordered (strict).

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What do you mean we can't compare $u,v$ in th elast case? In tha case, *by definition* $u<v$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen they belong to different sets and we don't have an order

Comment: Does $A \sqcup B$ mean the disjoint union of $A$ and $B$? If it is just the union, and the sets have a common element, then there is a problem: if $c \in A \cap B$, you get $c < c$. If it is the disjoint union, it works as Hagen von Eitzen explains.

Comment: @amrsa it represents the disjoint union indeed

Comment: I'm shifting the comment to the original question in order not to keep bugging Hagen von Eitzen. If I understood you right (your comment 1 hour ago), yes, and that's what I said some 5 hours ago. It's just a matter of reading the definition of the order on $X$: if $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ then $a < b$. For example, if $A$ has a top element, and $B$ has a bottom one, then just make the top of $A$ less than the bottom of $B$, and the rest is just as in $A$ and $B$ (applying transitivity, of course).

Comment: Still about your last comment, the answer to your question is clearly yes. Then you say something which is not very clear to me. We don't put the two posets side by side, it's $B$ on top of $A$. The most simple case: if $A$ and $B$ are singletons, then $X$ is a two element chain.

Comment: @amrsa It begins to enter in my brain and I saw it with $\mathbb{N}\amalg \mathbb{Z}^{-}$

Comment: Yes, that's an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order $<_X$ is strict:

- If $x\in X$ then $x\not <x$ because each of $(x\in A, x<_Ax)$,  $(x\in B, x<_Bx)$,  $(x\in A, x\in B)$ is false
- If $x<y$ and $y<z$ then $x<z$: If $x\in B$, then $y<_Xy$ implies $y\in B$ and $x<_By$. Then $y<_XZ$ implies $z\in B$ and $y<_Bz$, hence $x<_Bz$ and $x<_Xz$. Similarly, if $z\in A$, then $y\in A$ and $y<_Az$; then $x\in A$ and $x<_Ay$, hence $x<_Az$ and $x<_Xz$. Finally, if $x\in A$ and $z\in B$, we have $x<_Xz$ immediately.

If $<A,<_B$ are additionally total, then $<_X$ is also total: If $x,y\in X$ then either both are in $A$ and hence comparable, or both are in $B$ and hence comparable, or one is in $A$ and the other in B$ and hence they are comparable.

If $<_A,<_B$ are additionally well-orders, then so is $<_X$. If $S\subset X$ is non-empty, the either $S\subseteq B$, which makes $\min_X(S)=\min_B(S)$; or $S\cap A$ is non-empty and we find $\min_X(S)=\min_A(S\cap A)$.

Comment: We don't have an order on $A\times B$ I don't understand why we can compare elements

Comment: @Maman We can compare precisely because we define it so, that is, we put the $(B,<_B)$ above $(A,<_A)$, thus extending the order of both posets to their union. For example, if in $A$ and $B$ are finite, just add the coverings $(a,b)$ such that $a$ is maximal in $A$ and $b$ is minimal in $B$.

Comment: @amrsa You can compare elements of $B$ with $<_B$ and elements of $A$ with $<_A$ but which order do you take to compare $x\in A$ and $y\in B$ ?

Comment: @Maman The order you have specifically defined above: that every element of $B$ is greater than every element of $A$. I don't know what kind of bibliography you have available, but in _Davey & Priestley, Introduction to Lattices and Order_, they call _linear sum_ of $A$ and $B$ to this construction, and denote it by $A \oplus B$. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Sums_of_partially_ordered_sets

Comment: @amrsa so if $x\in A$ and $y\in B$ I have automatically $x<_X y$ ? I mean it's like we draw a line $A$ then a little gap the a line $B$ and we compare elements from left to right ?